# Error while parsing object Contract received through Metadata API caused by restrictedPicklist

Tags: metadata-api, sobject

I retrieve SObjects using **retrieve()** call from Metadata API and then I'm trying to parse them like described [here in comment](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22003/parsing-metadata-api-xml).

The problem occurs while trying to parse standard object **Contract**. It throws following:

> com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Unexpected element. Parser was expecting element 'http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata:sorted' but found 'http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata:restrictedPicklist'

When I unzip received objects and drop line

**< restrictedPicklist> true < /  restrictedPicklist >**

from **Contract.object**, it works fine.

So it looks like somewhere different API versions are used. But I checked everywhere - my endpoints, my generated jars, my force-wsc.jar - 33 is everywhere (and before I tried 32).

Am I missing something (I mean if I should define API Version somewhere else)?

Or is it their bug?

Or this SObject was created in older API Version and I can't solve that using the new one in that case?

Thank you.